# REGEX_SUBSTR Redshift

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

I need to extract the day and month from a campaign code, but my query only returns NULL values.  The day and month always follow the format of 'mmmdd' (e.g., aug23, sep12, oct09) although the campaign values vary in total length.

Sample Query:

```
SELECT Campaign,
       Year,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(campaign, '[a-z]{3}\d{2}') AS Month_Day

FROM GA_CAMPAIGN
```

Sample Table:

```
Campaign                                           | Year | Month_Day
TL-17-push-general-sep15septemberhighlights-0-0-0- | 17   | NULL
FA-17-stoke-aug09augusthighlights-0-0-0-0-0        | 17   | NULL
```

Desired Output:

```
Campaign                                           | Year | Month_Day
TL-17-push-general-sep15septemberhighlights-0-0-0- | 17   | sep15
FA-17-stoke-aug09augusthighlights-0-0-0-0-0        | 17   | aug09
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use a redshift python UDF to fully solve this. if nobody comes up with a regex solution I will help you with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\d` is not working as you expect. Try using `[0-9]` instead.

```
WITH sample AS (
          SELECT 'TL-17-push-general-sep15septemberhighlights-0-0-0' campaign
UNION ALL SELECT 'FA-17-stoke-aug09augusthighlights-0-0-0-0-0'       campaign
)
SELECT campaign,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(campaign, '[a-z]{3}[0-9]{2}') AS Month_Day
FROM sample
;
--                     campaign                      | month_day
-----------------------------------------------------+-----------
-- TL-17-push-general-sep15septemberhighlights-0-0-0 | sep15
-- FA-17-stoke-aug09augusthighlights-0-0-0-0-0       | aug09
```